# google cloud cannot connect to mongodb cluster

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-app-engine, mongoose, google-cloud-platform

I have a MongoDB Cluster in MongoDB Atlas and I use this MONGO_URI that they provided to connect to it. The format is something like this:

```
mongodb://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@cluster0-shard-00-00-nnn.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-nnn.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-nnn.gcp.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true
```

When I run my node.js program locally, I can read and write the database. However, when I deploy to google cloud, I'm having connecting to it. This is what I see in Google Console:

```
  Mongoose connection "error" event fired with: 
  { MongoError: connection 5 to cluster0-shard-00-02-32tq4.mongodb.net:27017 closed 
      at Function.MongoError.create (/srv/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:29:11) 
      at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:214:22) 
      at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30) 
      at emitOne (events.js:121:20) 
      at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7) 
      at _handle.close (net.js:557:12) 
      at Socket.done (_tls_wrap.js:356:7) 
      at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30) 
      at emitOne (events.js:116:13) 
      at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7) 
      at TCP._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:557:12)
```

I've tried to add `allow-mongodb` to firewall with protocols and ports as `tcp:27017`, direction `ingress`, IP ranges `0.0.0.0/0` and it's still not working. Can someone tell me what I'm missing here?

P.S I'm kinda suspecting that I have to add my mongodb cluster's IP to firewall as well though I'm not sure

Comment: How are you deploying that node application?

Comment: @RobertMoskal nvm, I figured out - I used a wrong URI